# Piping to 'tee' commands prevents changes in environment variables

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, csh

I have a csh script using which I modify certain environment variables and echo values of these environment variables from within this script. I source this from another script:

```
source "$BUILD_SCRIPT_DIR"/set_env
```

Everything was working fine. Later I decided to send the printed information from the above script to a logfile using the 'tee' command as I wanted to display the information on standard output as well:

```
source "$BUILD_SCRIPT_DIR"/set_env | tee $BUILD_LOG
```

However, due to this, changes in environment variable made in the sourced script stopped getting reflected in the sourcing script. Is there a workaround for this?